# Make scrollbars flash from code (like iOS flashScrollIndicators)

Tags: android, scrollbar, scrollview

In iOS there is the `flashScrollIndicators` method on the `UIScrollView` class that allows you to make the scrollbars flash briefly like they do when the view is first displayed.

I can't find in the documentation the Android equivalent to this, to make the scrollbars flash briefly on scrollable views (ScrollView, ListView, WebView, etc). I tried issuing a `requestLayout()` on the view, but that didn't work.

The reason I'm asking this, is because my views are contained in a `ViewPager` and when the user swipes to a different page, that page has often already been drawn and doesn't flash the scrollbars.

**answering my own question here**

The method is called `awakenScrollBars` and is defined in the `View` class. Unfortunately the method is `protected` so you will have to subclass the ScrollView, ListView or whatever view you want to have its scrollbars flashed.

Alternatively, the *public* methods `scrollTo` and `scrollBy` also flash the scrollbars but only if the scroll position has actually changed. So f.e. `listView.scrollBy(0,0)` won't work and `listView.scrollTo(0,0)` only works if the view wasn't already at the top.

If are unable to subclass the view, the following seems to work, although admittedly it's kind of a hack:

```
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Setting the view to invisible and then immediately to visible again doesn't seem to cause any redraws, but it has the side-effect of triggering the scrollbar flashing.

Answer (score 5):

I solved a similar problem by forcing it to scroll up and down directly after each other.

```
scrollView.scrollBy(0, 1);
scrollView.scrollBy(0, -1);
```

This causes the scroll view to show the vertical scrollbar, unless there is nothing to scroll.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the scrollview was already at the bottom, it is now 1 pixel above the bottom due to the -1 scroll

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting `isScrollbarFadingEnabled = false` first to force scrollbar appear and then scroll it a bit and then `isScrollbarFadingEnabled = true` to make it disappear.

code below in Kotlin:

```
scrollview.isScrollbarFadingEnabled = false
        handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
            scrollview.isScrollbarFadingEnabled = true
            scrollview.scrollBy(1, 0)
        }, 600)
```